# Intercept/handle browser's back button in React-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I'm using Material-ui's Tabs, which are controlled and I'm using them for (React-router) Links like this:

```
    <Tab value={0} label="dashboard" containerElement={<Link to="/dashboard/home"/>}/>
    <Tab value={1} label="users" containerElement={<Link to="/dashboard/users"/>} />
  <Tab value={2} label="data" containerElement={<Link to="/dashboard/data"/>} />
```

If I'm currenlty visting dashboard/data and I click browser's back button
I go (for example) to dashboard/users but the highlighted Tab still stays on dashboard/data (value=2)

I can change by setting state, but I don't know how to handle the event when the browser's back button is pressed?

I've found this:

```
window.onpopstate = this.onBackButtonEvent;
```

but this is called each time state is changed (not only on back button event)

Comment: I know it is late, but call it in **useEffect** with empty params like : `useEffect(()=>{/* here */}, [])`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

here is how I ended up doing it:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this._isMounted = true;
    window.onpopstate = ()=> {
      if(this._isMounted) {
        const { hash } = location;
        if(hash.indexOf('home')>-1 && this.state.value!==0)
          this.setState({value: 0})
        if(hash.indexOf('users')>-1 && this.state.value!==1)
          this.setState({value: 1})
        if(hash.indexOf('data')>-1 && this.state.value!==2)
          this.setState({value: 2})
      }
    }
  }
```

thanks everybody for helping lol

Comment: it is not a react way

Comment: The "react way" is overly restrictive and byzantine.

Comment: this is the only working solution if you use nextjs. native nextjs router event listeners don't see "back" click in browser

Comment: Any way to do this using hook in nextjs? `useEffect` ?

Answer (score 63):

Using react-router made the job simple as such:

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

componentDidMount() {
    this.onScrollNearBottom(this.scrollToLoad);

    this.backListener = browserHistory.listen((loc, action) => {
      if (action === "POP") {
        // Do your stuff
      }
    });
  }

componentWillUnmount() {
    // Unbind listener
    this.backListener();
}
```

Comment: doesn't work for me. using react-router@3.0.5, location.action is always PUSH, even when clicking the browser back button

Comment: @loopmode when you handle the back button action, to you use something like ```browserHistory.goBack()```??

Comment: I found that elsewhere, a colleague is meddling with the history manually, something along the lines

            if (nextLocation.action === 'POP' && getStepIndex(nextLocation.pathname) === 0) {
                browserHistory.push({pathname: `${getPathForIndex(0)}`});
                return false;
            }

so.. `if POP then PUSH` in order to make the forward button unavailable (which would go forward without a form being submitted)

So.. Your answer remains correct - user error on my side :)

Comment: As of react-router@5.0.0 you can't import `browserHistory` as illustrated in this response. It appears that `history` is included in the `props` passed to any component that is referenced from a route. Feel free to correct me if that's not quite right.

Comment: I think it is the history.action === "POP" and also it happens with refresh too

Comment: For anyone using React Router 4+, then the listen has 2 parameters, location and action. `history.listen((loc, action) => if (action === 'POP') // do stuff)`

Comment: how do i prevent the POP from being executed though?

Answer (score 54):

Using hooks you can detect the back and forward buttons

```js
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'


const [ locationKeys, setLocationKeys ] = useState([])
const history = useHistory()

useEffect(() => {
  return history.listen(location => {
    if (history.action === 'PUSH') {
      setLocationKeys([ location.key ])
    }

    if (history.action === 'POP') {
      if (locationKeys[1] === location.key) {
        setLocationKeys(([ _, ...keys ]) => keys)

        // Handle forward event

      } else {
        setLocationKeys((keys) => [ location.key, ...keys ])

        // Handle back event

      }
    }
  })
}, [ locationKeys, ])
```

Comment: What's the  _ (underscore) in setLocationKeys(([ _, ...keys ]) => keys)

Comment: @ShabbirEssaji It uses [destructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and the spread operator, to return an array with the first element removed. [This may help](https://codeburst.io/a-simple-guide-to-destructuring-and-es6-spread-operator-e02212af5831)

Comment: @ShabbirEssaji you probably found your answer by now, but an underscore is used a lot by convention when a variable must be assigned but won't be used.

Comment: is this still a good way to handle both back and forward or has anything been added to deal with the arguably hacky `locationKeys, setLocationKeys` bit? yet. pls. ty

Comment: So far yes, this is the best solution we have.

Comment: It'a a nice solution, but IMHO not what requested. The request is "How to intercept/handle the back button", but this code triggered even if a new url is set per code.

Comment: The `locationKeys` are set in react state. May I know their purpose?  Can it be used to modify the `location` and `location.state`, so that additional info can be passed in state in the back button click / pop action? If so, how?

Answer (score 25):

Hooks sample

```
const {history} = useRouter();
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      // && history.location.pathname === "any specific path")
      if (history.action === "POP") {
        history.replace(history.location.pathname, /* the new state */);
      }
    };
  }, [history])
```

I don't use history.listen because it doesn't affect the state

```
const disposeListener = history.listen(navData => {
        if (navData.pathname === "/props") {
            navData.state = /* the new state */;
        }
    });
```

Comment: i would change the dependency array to [history.location, history.action] because it wont catch the location changes

Comment: Isn't `useRouter()` specific to the Next.js framework?

Comment: I could only find a `useRouter()` function in the `useHooks` library: https://usehooks.com/useRouter/

Answer (score 13):

Most of the answers for this question either use outdated versions of React Router, rely on less-modern Class Components, or are confusing; and none use Typescript, which is a common combination. Here is an answer using Router v5, function components, and Typescript:

```
// use destructuring to access the history property of the ReactComponentProps type
function MyComponent( { history }: ReactComponentProps) {

    // use useEffect to access lifecycle methods, as componentDidMount etc. are not available on function components.
    useEffect(() => {

        return () => {
            if (history.action === "POP") {
                // Code here will run when back button fires. Note that it's after the `return` for useEffect's callback; code before the return will fire after the page mounts, code after when it is about to unmount.
                }
           }
    })
}
```

A fuller example with explanations can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61939358/how-to-intercept-back-button-in-a-react-spa-using-function-components-and-react).

Answer (score 9):

Version 3.x of the React Router API has [a set of utilities](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3/docs/guides/ConfirmingNavigation.md) you can use to expose a "Back" button event before the event registers with the browser's history.  You must first wrap your component in the [`withRouter()` higher-order component](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md). You can then use the `setRouteLeaveHook()` function, which accepts any `route` object with a valid `path` property and a callback function.

```
import {Component} from 'react';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';

class Foo extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.router.setRouteLeaveHook(this.props.route, this.routerWillLeave);
  }

  routerWillLeave(nextState) { // return false to block navigation, true to allow
    if (nextState.action === 'POP') {
      // handle "Back" button clicks here
    }
  }
}

export default withRouter(Foo);
```

Comment: For me its just giving an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setRouteLeaveHook' of undefined`

Comment: @NikitaVlasenko Expanding on the example above, `Foo` needs to be passed to a `<Route />` component, or at the very least needs to inherit a route component's props. (E.g., in your `routes.js` file, `<Route component={Foo}>/* ... */</Route>`)

Answer (score 8):

Using hooks. I have converted @Nicolas Keller's code to typescript

```
  const [locationKeys, setLocationKeys] = useState<(string | undefined)[]>([]);
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    return history.listen((location) => {
      if (history.action === 'PUSH') {
        if (location.key) setLocationKeys([location.key]);
      }

      if (history.action === 'POP') {
        if (locationKeys[1] === location.key) {
          setLocationKeys(([_, ...keys]) => keys);

          // Handle forward event
          console.log('forward button');
        } else {
          setLocationKeys((keys) => [location.key, ...keys]);

          // Handle back event
          console.log('back button');
          removeTask();
        }
      }
    });
  }, [locationKeys]);
```

Comment: What does the _ do

Comment: @KshitijV97 That means "ignore this variable", additionally the convention of `_` can be used like this `_firstElement`, and this `_firstElement` won't cause any warning/error even if it's not used.

Answer (score 5):

in NextJs we can use beforePopState function and do what we want such close modal or show a modal or check the back address and decide what to do

```
const router = useRouter();

useEffect(() => {
    router.beforePopState(({ url, as, options }) => {
        // I only want to allow these two routes!

        if (as === '/' ) {
            // Have SSR render bad routes as a 404.
             window.location.href = as;
            closeModal();
            return false
        }

        return true
    })
}, [])
```

Answer (score 4):

I used withrouter hoc in order to get history prop and just write a componentDidMount() method:

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.history.action === "POP") {
        // custom back button implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: It is triggering before click back button, Can you help on this?, we need to trigger a custom popup after click back button.

Answer (score 4):

For giving warning on the press of browser back in react functional components. do the following steps

1. declare isBackButtonClicked and initialize it as false and maintain the state using setBackbuttonPress function.

```
const [isBackButtonClicked, setBackbuttonPress] = useState(false);
```

2. In componentdidmount, add the following lines of code

```
window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
window.addEventListener('popstate', onBackButtonEvent);
```

3. define onBackButtonEvent Function and write logic as per your requirement.

   ```
     const onBackButtonEvent = (e) => {
     e.preventDefault();
     if (!isBackButtonClicked) {

     if (window.confirm("Do you want to go to Test Listing")) {
       setBackbuttonPress(true)
       props.history.go(listingpage)
     } else {
       window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
       setBackbuttonPress(false)
     }
   }
   ```

   }
4. In componentwillmount unsubscribe onBackButtonEvent Function

Final code will look like this

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react'

function HandleBrowserBackButton() {
  const [isBackButtonClicked, setBackbuttonPress] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {

    window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
    window.addEventListener('popstate', onBackButtonEvent);

    //logic for showing popup warning on page refresh
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {

      return "Data will be lost if you leave the page, are you sure?";
    };
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('popstate', onBackButtonEvent);
    }

    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
  const onBackButtonEvent = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!isBackButtonClicked) {

      if (window.confirm("Do you want to go to Test Listing")) {
        setBackbuttonPress(true)
        props.history.go(listingpage)
      } else {
        window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
        setBackbuttonPress(false)
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default HandleBrowserBackButton
```

Answer (score 3):

Upcoming version 6 introduces [useBlocker](https://reactrouter.com/en/6.22.3/hooks/use-blocker) hook - which could be used to intercept all navigation attempts.

```
import { useBlocker } from 'react-router';

// when blocker should be active
const unsavedChanges = true;

let blocker = useBlocker(
  ({ historyAction }) => unsavedChanges && historyAction === "POP"
)
```

```
{ blocker.state === "blocked" ? (
  <div>
    <p>Are you sure you want to leave?</p>
    <button onClick={()=> blocker.proceed()}>
      Proceed
    </button>
    <button onClick={()=> blocker.reset()}>
      Cancel
    </button>
  </div>
) : null }
```

Comment: This solution requires you are using a router that support the new data APIs: https://reactrouter.com/en/6.22.3/routers/picking-a-router

Answer (score 3):

If you are using React Router V5, you can try [Prompt](https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Prompt).

> Used to prompt the user before navigating away from a page. When your application enters a state that should prevent the user from navigating away (like a form is half-filled out), render a <Prompt>

```
<Prompt
   message={(location, action) => {
   if (action === 'POP') {
      console.log("Backing up...")
      // Add your back logic here
   }

   return true;
   }}
/>
```

Comment: You should include the back logic

Answer (score 3):

just put in componentDidMount()

```js
componentDidMount() {
    window.onbeforeunload =this.beforeUnloadListener;
} 
beforeUnloadListener = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    return event.returnValue = "Are you sure you want to exit?";
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Add these 2 lines in to your componentDidMount().This worked for me

```
window.history.pushState(null, null, document.URL);
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
      window.location.replace(
        `YOUR URL`
      );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of Router you use in React.

If you use BrowserRouter from react-router (not available in react-router v4 though), as mentioned above, you can use the action 'POP' to intercept the browser back button.

However, if you use HashRouter to push the routes, above solution will not work. The reason is hash router always triggered with 'POP' action when you click browser back button or pushing the route from your components. You cant differentiate these two actions either with window.popstate or history.listen simply.

Comment: Any hack while using hashRouter? Prompt is triggered after url changes in the browser

Answer (score 1):

**kajkal**'s answer (on Jul 24, 2020 at 23:27) was the closest answer for me, but it required upgrading my react router version and I wanted to avoid making a large change.

Ultimately, interrupting the browser back button seems to be an anti-pattern and the suggested approach is to save user data in session storage/reload it; that way you do not degrade the UX by blocking browser functions. This was also too big a change for me.

The other solutions didn't work because of my react router version.

I did come across a snippet that works for me, which uses the default browser exit confirm dialog (tested on Chrome). It's worth noting that this event is triggered by browser back button but, crucially, also by browser forward button and browser refresh:

```
const shouldShowBrowserExitConfirmDialog = true;
```

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if (shouldShowBrowserExitConfirmDialog) {
      // The default message CANNOT be overridden
      return "Changes that you made may not be saved.";
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  };
```

This is what the dialog looks like on chrome:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To handle browser back button click/press after navigation, follow the following steps

**STEP 1:**

Create callback function to handle back press/click `useBackButton`

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const useBackButton = (callback) => {
const [isBack, setIsBack] = useState(false);

const handleEvent = () => {
setIsBack(true);
callback();
window.history.go(1);
};

useEffect(() => {
window.addEventListener("popstate", handleEvent);
return () => window.removeEventListener("popstate", handleEvent);
});

return isBack;
};

 export default useBackButton;
```

**STEP 2:**

> When click on browser back or forward button. if you want to redirect to 'home' page, you can replace '/' with your homepage route (e.g. '/home' or '/' etc.).

`import` function in your respective component to handle back click

```
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router";
import useBackButton from "../hooks/useBackButton";

const MyPage = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const toDo = () => {
  navigate("/");
};

const isBackPressed = useBackButton(toDo);
return <div>My Page</div>;
};

export default MyPage;
```

Answer (score -7):

You can use "withrouter" HOC and use `this.props.history.goBack`.

```
<Button onClick={this.props.history.goBack}>
    BACK
</Button>
```

Comment: This illustrates how to create a back button, not intercept the browser's back button, as the OP requested.