# Prevent history navigation from causing reload in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In React, `this.props.history.goback()` and `this.props.history.go(-1)` are used to go back to the previous page in the browser. However, these cause the page to hard-reset (i.e., reload) when redirecting to the previous page.

Is there any way to prevent the page from refreshing in an SPA using React?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intercept/handle browser's back button in React-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39342195/intercept-handle-browsers-back-button-in-react-router)

Answer (score 1):

If you use [`BrowserRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter), there should be no reloading within your origin.

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

<BrowserRouter>
    <App/>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `window.history.back()`.

HTML

```
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>
```

JavaScript

```
function goBack() {
    window.history.back();
}
```

Comment: this does not work