# I wanted to redirect to a component when someone hit the browser's back button in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have tried some of the window methods in component did mount but it wasn't working.

Comment: please update the question with more information and code snippet.
also are you using react-router-dom? if so then use the history api to change the url. history.push('/'); 

also note that window methods wont work and cause reload.

Comment: yes i am using react-router-dom.
this. is what i was trying in componentdidmount()
 window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event) {
            if (event.state) {
                alert('!!');
                window.location.replace("/Error/?message= oops! error occured. Do not hit the back button");
            }
        }, false);

Comment: did you checked out this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39342195/intercept-handle-browsers-back-button-in-react-router