# How to pass params when user clicks BackButton in browser in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm Using react ,

1. Intially the user will be  in '/page1'
2. He selects a course from the dropdown and he clicks continue button
3. he will be redirected to '/page2' , selected course_id is present in  page 2 component props
4. Now what i am trying to do is , when the user clicks back button in the browser he is redirected to '/page1' , but instead i need to '/page1?course=course_id" , so that the course which he has selected initially is now pre-selected..

Comment: Hi could you include a [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: You need to use local storage or redux store. You can set `course_id` in local storage or redux store when you reach page2. In `componentDidMount` of page1, you can get URL from local storage or redux store.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39342195/intercept-handle-browsers-back-button-in-react-router?noredirect=1&lq=1 Try to intercept the default action