# browser back button does not re-render component after router.push

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router

**Scenario :**

I am on Page A which have a X component that has state sunny = false initially. after I did some operation in component; state is updated to sunny = true. now I route.push(Page B). when I navigate back to Page A using browser back button I see component X has stale state 'sunny' = true. I want it to reset to sunny = false.

Is it bug in nextjs route? If not how can I force particular component to re-render so not using stale states

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intercept/handle browser's back button in React-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39342195/intercept-handle-browsers-back-button-in-react-router)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not a bug.

Depending on the router that you use, the solution can be different. But this is the "JavaScript way" of handling your routing.

```
componentDidMount() {
  // to make sure window.onpopstate is fired went his page is opened.
  this._isMounted = true;
  window.onpopstate = () => {
    if(this._isMounted) {
      // set state to initial state.
    }
  }
}
```

source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39363278/7552329

Comment: how to do this with functional components?

Answer (score -1):

You can pass query parameters as below:

```
Router.push({
    pathname: '/about',
    query: { name: 'Someone' }
})
```

and access it to change the state

Comment: How will passing `query` parameter will be useful in this case. since I want to reset state on Page A, and query parameter will be accessible in page B

Comment: you can use that param to update the state