# Prevent going to the previous page on browser back button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-router

I have a Next.js / React.js project I'm working on and I'm trying to redirect to a certain page when browser's back button is clicked. My approach is as follows

```
useEffect(() => {
    Router?.beforePopState(({ as }) => {
        if (as !== router.asPath) {
            handleRouteChange({ toHref: getRoutingPath('HOME') }, Router.push);
        }
        return true;
    });
        
    return () => {
        Router?.beforePopState(() => true);
    };
}, [dispatch, router]);
```

And this code works. When I click the back button, it takes me to the home page as intended.

But the issue is, when I click on the back button, it takes me to the previous page for a second and then redirects to the home page. How can I prevent going to the previous page at all?

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39342195/intercept-handle-browsers-back-button-in-react-router#:~:text=It%20depends%20on%20the%20type,intercept%20the%20browser%20back%20button.

Answer (score 4):

You can return `false` from the `beforePopState` callback to disable Next.js handling the routing automatically and handle it yourself.

From the [`router.beforePopState`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerbeforepopstate) documentation:

> If `cb` returns `false`, the Next.js router will not handle
> `popstate`, and you'll be responsible for handling it in that case.
> See [Disabling file-system
> routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server#disabling-file-system-routing).

```js
useEffect(() => {
    router.beforePopState(({ as }) => {
        if (as !== router.asPath) {
            handleRouteChange({ toHref: getRoutingPath('HOME') }, Router.push);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
    
    return () => {
        router.beforePopState(() => true);
    };
}, [router]);
```

Comment: Great answer! This is the first I've seen of this non-hack to prevent route changes.

Comment: This does not seem to work, i'm still seeing the previous "back" route flash briefly before pushing to a different route (like in the example above). What could cause this?