# Close a modal when user clicks back button in browser React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am showing user a modal that takes over the entire screen if user is accessing the website on phone. A user tends to instinctively click the back button on their phone to go back to the previous screen instead of using the close button provided on the modal.

Is there a way to intercept the function that is triggered when a user clicks the back button? I want to close the modal when user clicks the back button on their phone, instead of having them redirect to the previous page.

Comment: I think you're looking for something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39342195/intercept-handle-browsers-back-button-in-react-router

Comment: @derFrosty it provides a partial answer. With this, I am able to execute some code before the user is redirected. However, I want to prevent user from redirecting and only close the modal.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/History). An example on how to acomplish this is:

```
//listen for state changes
window.onpopstate = (event) => 
{
   if (!event.state.modalOpened)
   {
     closeModal()
   }
}

//change the actual page state so it contains the modalOpened property
window.history.replaceState({modalOpened: false})

function openModal(content) 
{
    //push new state, put the modal information in the state object, this will push a new state, when the user presses the back button, the browser will just trigger the onpopstate event, instead of going to the previous page
    window.history.replaceState({modalOpened: true})

    //this is any code you use to open your modal, for example
    ReactDOM.render(<Modal>{content}</Modal>, document.getElementById("modal-container")
}
```

**class based component**

There are many ways to aproach this, this is one of them, everything you need to make something that fits with your app is in the History API DOCS.

```
//listen for state changes
    window.onpopstate = (event) => 
    {
       if (!event.state.modalOpened)
       {
         updateModal(false, null)
       }
    }

function openModal()
{
//push new state, put the modal information in the state object, this will push a new state, when the user presses the back button, the browser will just trigger the onpopstate event, instead of going to the previous page
        window.history.replaceState({modalOpened: true})
        updateModal(false, <div>Modal content!</div>)
}

function updateModal(open, content)
{
   ReactDOM.render(<Modal open={open} content={content} />, document.getElementById("modal-container")
}

//change the actual page state so it contains the modalOpened property
    window.history.replaceState({modalOpened: false})

class Modal extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    //check the history to determine if we have to open or close the modal
    return <div className={"modal " + (props.open)? "show" : ""}><div className="modal-content">{props.content}</div><button onClick={() => window.history.back()}>OK</button></div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Can you provide a solution for class based component? I am not sure how to use this.

Comment: It depends on how do you structure your app, I will try to give you another example later, but if you could provide some code so I can see how this could fit your app that would be great.

Comment: updated my answer, tell me if it is of any help

Comment: For reference, MDN states that `replaceState` requires the 'unused' param and it *should* be an empty String: `replaceState({modalOpened: false}, '')` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState