# after returning Parent route Trigger useEffect

Tags: reactjs

In my current React app, i have a route like

```
<Route path="products" element={<Products />}>
     <Route path=":productId" element={<Product />} />
</Route>
```

in the Products component, I have an `useEffect` where I fetch all products.
In the product component, I have another `useEffect` where I fetch a single product.
Users can edit that product.
in this component, a back button navigates the user to the "/products" route. But this time `useEffect`was not triggered in the Products component so updated information on the Product component is not reflected here.

Comment: can you post the code causing the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intercept/handle browser's back button in React-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39342195/intercept-handle-browsers-back-button-in-react-router)

Answer (score 0):

The `useEffect` inside `Prodcuts` will not be triggered because it is unaware of the change in the products.

You are fetching twice and each fetch is independent of the other as far as React is concerned. One solution is to store the results of the first fetch in state and then modify it in `Product` which will trigger `useEffect`.