# EventListener wont invoke callback method when reffered by name

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm working on a React application and I'm trying to listen to back button click events so I can customize the navigation flow.  I've created the following hook:

```
export default function useBackButton(
  goTo: string,
) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  useEffect(() => {
    window.history.pushState(null, "", document.URL);
    window.addEventListener("popstate", backButtonHandler);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("popstate", backButtonHandler);
  });
  function backButtonHandler(event) {
      navigate(goTo, { replace: true });
    }
  }
```

The problem with the code is that the callback method "backButtonHandler" in ...

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", backButtonHandler);
```

... will not be invoked.

It will only work if I add it as inline logic:

```
 window.addEventListener("popstate", (event) => navigate(goTo, { replace: true });
```

I my case I need to provide the logic through a method declaration since I need to remove the listener.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't change the browser back button behavior to "trap" users inside your web page/app, it's poor UI/UX.

Answer (score 1):

You're forgetting a dependency array in your `useEffect`. This leads the event listener to be added and removed on each render. Just add an empty array as a dependency.

Comment: thanks..but adding the empty array as dependecy didn't help,  dosen't still invoke.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to listen to `back button` events you can create a `function` like this:

```
 const BackButtonListener = ({ children }) => {
  const [pressed, setPressed] = React.useState(false)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.onpopstate = e => {
      setPressed(true)
    };
  });
 return (
    <h3>Back button: {pressed.toString()}</h3>
  );
};
```

Then, include the same in your `component` as follows:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        ...
        <BackButtonListener />
        ...
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Reference link: [Intercept/handle browser's back button in React-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39342195/intercept-handle-browsers-back-button-in-react-router)